# How to build signed release version of Android Wear watch face the correct way?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to build a signed APK of an android wear face. Since I've been running into trouble, I'm trying to do this as a proof of concept with the default template project in Android Studio 1.2.1.1 on Mac OS X.

These are the steps I took:

1. Start a new project in Android Studio
2. Tick "Phone and Tablet" (Minimum API 18) and "Wear" (Minimum API 21)
3. Select "No Activity" for Mobile
4. Select "Watch Face" for Wear, give it a name and select the "Analog" type
5. Press on Build -> Generate Signed APK
6. Select to build the "mobile" module
7. Create a new key store, and fill in all the information
8. Select this key store with the key alias
9. Select my desktop as the destination folder, set the build type to "release"
10. This produces two APK files on my desktop: mobile-release.apk and wear-release.apk. I transfer the mobile-release.apk to my phone for installation.

After installation of the signed mobile-release.apk, the watch face never shows up in the Android Wear companion application, nor on the watch itself. It does show up in the list of downloaded applications in the settings though. I've tried waiting, and I've tried resyncing apps to the watch. What am I doing wrong? How do I properly build a release version of an Android Wear watch face?

Comment: I get the watch face deployed properly following these steps with Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows. I assume that you didn't change anything in the build scripts. Take a look into your .apk, does it contain wearable apk inside? You can open your apk as a zip archive, and then navigate to /res/raw folder, a micro apk should be in there. Also, take a look into logcat, see if package installer nags about something. I had a case with emulated wearable device, which had older google play services than my project required.